# Ada aws (ada web server) in windows 10

Tags: webserver, installation, ada, gprinstall

Good afternoon. Please tell what I'm doing wrong. I installed GNAT 2016 in windows10. copied aws (ada web server) repository to the desktop, opened as it is written build.cmd and run

build C:\GNAT\2016, further the console wrote

C:\Users...\Desktop\aws-gpl-2016-src\win32>build 
C:\Users...\Desktop\aws-gpl-2016-src
The system cannot find the path specified.
gprbuild.exe: project file "config\setup" not found in .;;C:\GtkAda\lib\gnat
Couldn't build or install AWS

what happened and how can I fix it?

I tried in Linux Ubuntu to Fedora but still not going to. I followed the instructions posted on the Libre hell
When I installed gnat in windose all set, PATH, a permanent resident in the environment variables C: \ GNAT \ 2016ebin here simply do not know what to do next I'm in Ada beginner, Can tell me how to raise the minimum Hello server at least. There are also experienced and knowledgeable people in

Comment: It turns out to build the project of the aws in windows 10 need gprbuild [ .gpr] [switches] [names] {[-cargs opts] [-cargs: lang opts] [-largs opts] [-gargs opts]} and if need to build a separate project aws example hello server also use gprbuild all ways?

Comment: I don't know that it's _required_; for reference, the documentation should be in the distribution in the vicinity of `share/doc/gprbuild`.

Comment: Thanks! I put the Gnat 2016, and did according to the instructions on the AWS http://docs.adacore.com/aws-docs/aws/
Could you tell me more like you got run aws example (any OS), simply vebsoket( for example. I tried to run through GPS GPR project but the project was empty. in the same document states that the VSC++, I set Visual Studio and QT, not build.Cygwin have not tried

Comment: Maybe need to install something else besides just GNAT 2016.
And you did not try to run something for STM32 board microcontroller port and not just the finished project to flash? Simply, he is also not clear how to run)

Comment: On Windows, you may have to open the chosen port; see also [*Gem #29: Introduction to the Ada Web Server (AWS)*](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-29/).

Comment: The problem is that the chase in 2016 GNAT and aws the  fails to build(not only me), try to take an example of which you said, and to build, and how to build if no aws build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should do

```
cd C:\Users...\Desktop\aws-gpl-2016-src\
win32\build.cmd c:\gnat\2014
```

instead of running this from win32 directory.

Beside this there is a bug in this script in aws-gpl-2016, so you need to edit it by replacing line

```
gprinstall --prefix=%1 -p -f %GPROPTS% -XLIBRARY_TYPE=relocatable --build-name=relocatable aws.gpr
with:
gprinstall --prefix=%1 -p -f %GPROPTS% -XLIBRARY_TYPE=relocatable -XXMLADA_BUILD=relocatable --build-name=relocatable aws.gpr
```

Otherwise you will get an error after 'Install project Tools' message.

PS. Feel free to join Russian jabber room at ada-ru@conference.jabber.ru to ask about Ada.

Comment: I ran into win32 folder. 
and it is necessary from the folder where the project is aws.gpr Yes I agree then it's simple. I just do not understand correctly, thank you!

Comment: So, if this works for you, then you can mark my answer as useful :)